# How to find eigenvectors of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to find eigenvectors of the following matrix manually.

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 
300 & 100 & 75 \\
100 & 200 & 50 \\
75 & 50 & 100
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I found eigenvalues as 
$$
A1 = 389.809 \\
A2 = 71.864 \\
A3 = 138.325
$$

I substitute A1, in the equation of form

$$
(A - \lambda I ) \overline x = 0
$$
$ \overline x $  are eigenvectors.

When I do this substitution, I get following matrix:

A= \begin{bmatrix} 
-89.809 & 100 & 75 \\
100 & -189.809 & 50 \\
75 & 50 & -289.809
\end{bmatrix}

X =  \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3
\end{bmatrix}

B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}

$ AX=B $

My problem is to solve this system of equation. It seems that I can only get a trivial solution. If I assume, say $ x_3 = 1 $ still I am going wrong, if I compare my answer with matlab's.

Can someone help me how to get eigenvectors?

Comment: If you are interested in eigenvectors rather than eigenvalues you can divide all the elements of the matrix by $50$ to simplify the arithmetic.

Comment: If you want to solve for the eigenvectors by hand, you need to use the _exact_ eigenvalues, not the eigenvalues rounded to $3$ decimal places. Otherwise it doesn't work out. If you're using $A - \lambda'I$ where $\lambda'$ is _very close_ to an eigenvalue, then that matrix is not singular, and you'll only get the trivial solution.

Answer (score 1):

The point here is that if $\lambda A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix (with $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$) then
$$\sigma(\lambda A) = \lambda^n \sigma(A)$$

Where $\sigma$ is the spectrum with eigenvalues $\zeta$

So do yourself a favor and factor out $100$:

Then solving the characteristic equation becomes

$$100^3 [ (3-\zeta) ((2-\zeta)*(1-\zeta)-1*1) - 2(2*(1-\zeta)-1*1)+ 1.5 (2*1-2*1)]=0$$

perhaps you can get it from here?

Comment: Factoring out a large value from the matrix won't help much, as I am stuck at solving the linear system of equations. Even if I factor out, the system of equations will be still inconsistent and won't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have made an error somewhere: the eigenvalues for that matrix are, roughly: $ 516.65, 41.68 \pm 14.09î$ (or you have written down the wrong matrix).

The rest of your process and thinking is correct.

Comment: Sorry, I entered wrong matrix. Now I corrected that.